# Replace the value present in column B

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to macro I have created this macro to replace the values present in column B the macro button is not giving any error neither it is replacing values. but it executes properly... Please help me replacing... I tried if select it did not work then now I am trying with IF loop it does not work. please help me

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Dim i As Integer
Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet

Set ws = Worksheets("SampleFile")

For i = 1 To ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
If ws.Range("B" & i).Value = "FXV" Then
   ws.Range("B" & i).Value = "FFJ"
   ElseIf ws.Range("B" & i).Value = "FAM" Then
   ws.Range("B" & i).Value = "FST"
   ElseIf ws.Range("B" & i).Value = "FLB" Then
   ws.Range("B" & i).Value = "FST"
   End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: What do you mean by "but it executes properly"?

Comment: When I test with your code the result (from B2 to B4) is "FST", "FFH", "FFJ". How is that wrong? A mistake is however that you start your loop with cell B1, which is the header cell "Forwarder Code". So, it should be "For i = 2 to ..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

    Dim i As Long
    
    'Create a with statement with the worksheet we want to use
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SampleFile")
        
        'Start loop the lines
        For i = 1 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
            
            'Create a select statement
            Select Case UCase(.Range("B" & i).Value)
                Case "FXV"
                   .Range("B" & i).Value = "FFJ"
                Case "FAM"
                   .Range("B" & i).Value = "FST"
                Case "FLB"
                   .Range("B" & i).Value = "FST"
            End Select
            
        Next i
    
    End With
    
End Sub
```

**OR**

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    
    Dim arrFound As Variant, arrReplace As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    
    'Create an  array with the result to found
    arrFound = Array("FXV", "FAM", "FLB")
    'Create an array with the results to replace
    arrReplace = Array("FFJ", "FST", "FST")
    'For both arrays you have to put all values with the correct order
    
    'Create a with statement
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SampleFile")
        
        'Loop the array with the value you are looking for and replace with the according values
        For i = LBound(arrFound) To UBound(arrFound)
            .Range("B:B").Replace what:=arrFound(i), Replacement:=arrReplace(i), _
            LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, _
            SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
        Next i
        
    End With
    
End Sub
```

**OR**

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

    Dim i As Long
    
    'Create a woth statement with the worksheet we want to use
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SampleFile")
        
        'Start loop the lines
        For i = 1 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
            
            'Create a with statement
            If .Range("B" & i).Value = "FXV" Then
                .Range("B" & i).Value = "FFJ"
            ElseIf .Range("B" & i).Value = "FAM" Or .Range("B" & i).Value = "FLB" Then
                .Range("B" & i).Value = "FST"
            End If
            
        Next i
    
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Comment: I wonder which problem you answer? Probably you have also heard about what's wrong with code only answers. I'm sure you can explain the benefits of your two alternatives compared and how they answer OP's question.

Comment: @TomBrunberg i have explain the codes and import another solution